# Get value of variable from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the value of a variable, from a string, using JavaScript.

For example:

```
var string = "var example1 = 'Hello!'; var example2 = 'Goodbye!'";
string.getValueOfVariable("example1");
```

...Or something like that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to evaluate the string. It is not a great idea to evaluate code because it can cause XSS.

```js
function badIdea (code, theVar) {
  var x = new Function(`${code}; return ${theVar};`)
  return x()
}
var string = "var example1 = 'Hello!'; var example2 = 'Goodbye!'";
console.log(badIdea(string, 'example1'))
console.log(badIdea(string, 'example2'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain why using `eval()` is a bad idea? I'm using this for a Chrome Extension, not for my website.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function:

```js
var string = "var example1 = 'Hello!'; var example2 = 'Goodbye!'";
eval(string);
console.log(example1);
```

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use `eval()`.